# .xcassets Support for older IOS versions

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, xcode5

Any where i didn't find the backward compatabilty details for .xcassets template.

If i migrate the current images assets like appicon, launch images spotlight icons etc to  .xcassets template by using an option use assets catalog in settings in new xcode 5, will my app work in older versions like ios6 & 5 if i run in that.

And the naming conventions in code which already used for images will work properly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Mutawe Thanks for your quick response, just for confirmation have you tested it or any where apple clearly mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using asset catalog is compatible with only iOS 5 and above. You can set different icons to each (set icons compatible with iOS 5&6 and different ones to iOS 7).

Pay attention to 2 things:

1. You would need to have more sizes of the icons.
2. If your app is iPhone only if a user would run it on iPad with iOS 7 and you would put only iPhone icons the user would have a blank icon which is very ugly. For some reason you won't get any error but unlike Xcode 4.x you must to my opinion add iPad icons anyway no matter what app you are going to develop (all shall run also ion iPhone). to do that on assets catalog go to "identity inspector" and add the iPad icons (won't be added by default).