# Packaging UINavigationBar image resources for iOS6 / iO7

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I currently develop a sample app that I deliver white-branded to several entities based on their own visual entities.

Since iOS7 and the merge of the UIStatusBar with the UINavigationBar, I have to manage images in a lot of size : @2x for retina, -64h for iOS7 (64px height) and classical one.

I want to support both iOS 5, 6 & 7.

It is quite painful each time I want to deliver for specific entity to photoshop and resize 7 (even 8, here is missing the @2x for iPad) images.
At least for the Icon image it is quite easy as it remains a square whatever the targeted OS or device.

Is their a more productive to package it with fewer image resources ?

I am currently using the following code to set up my navbar image in all the app :

```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)

            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-64h.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        else

            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Comment: It depends on your image.  Have you looked at setting the background color to `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:…]`?

Comment: No, I must admit I did not. I should have a try.

Most of the time the image is composed of :
- a logo in the very center
- a solid background color (no gradient for instance), often white, some time something else (e.g, in case of a white logo)

Comment: For instance, I was wondering if could only use the iPad image as the content is centered and the iPad version just extends the solid background color, so if the iPhone reuse it by cropping left & right it would be great.

Comment: Oh, sounds like you are looking for `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:`], which will allow you to place the logo wherever you want, and have the pattern at the edges resize to fill any space.

Comment: Thanks, I will have deeper look at it and will let you know if it fits my need :)

Comment: Aaron, would you mind to provide a sample example ? Not sure on how to use UIEdgeInsets efficiently. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide just two images (regular and retina), using `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]`, or the Xcode 5 image slicer.

#### In code

For example:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1);  // represents a 1 point (2 pixel retina) border of your background color around your logo.

UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
navBackgroundImage = [navBackgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The `insets` should indicate the area of the image that isn't stretchable.

If you want more control over the placement of the logo, make the background color border larger than 1 point, and adjust `insets` to match.

You can provide different values of `insets` depending on your device, if necessary.

#### Xcode 5 Image Slicer

This code is equivalent to Xcode 5's image slicing editor in `xcassets` files, which is backwards compatible to iOS 5 [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503065/1445366).